# RegEx match x if foo or bar exists, but not if only bar exists

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write an expression that can match a whole string if it has a set of characters, but only if it contains a smaller subset of those characters.

To include my specific use case, I'd like this RegEx: `^[\w_\-]+$` (being that there can be alphanumeric characters, hyphens, and dashes), to match, but not to match if this RegEx is a match: `^[\d_\-]+$` (being that there must be at least one letter in the string, but it does not *have* to contain both letters and numbers).

Any of the allowed characters may be at any position, which makes the other relevant questions on this site not apply in my case.

- `foo-bar_123`: Match
- `123`: Not match
- `1-2-3`: Not match
- `1-a`: Match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[\w\-]+$`

Answer (score 2):

You can attempt to match the regular expression

```
^[\w\-]*[a-zA-Z][\w\-]*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zqLsak/1)

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be first matching the allowed characters without a character a-zA-Z

Then match at least a single a-zA-Z followed by all the allowed characters for the full match.

```
^[0-9_-]*[a-zA-Z][\w-]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[0-9_-]*` Match 0+ times a digit 0-9 or `_` or `-`
- `[a-zA-Z]` Match a single char a-zA-Z
- `[\w-]*` Match optional word chars or `-`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gB7tB2/1).

Comment: This one is very clever and efficient. Many thanks!